# Enviar email laravel 7 api rest

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

Tengo un endpoint de una api donde recibo datos de registro de un usuario, en este endpoint recibo un email del usuario donde debo enviar un email para su posterior confirmación pero no he podido realizar el envió, en mi función tengo:

```
try{
  $cliente->save(); //Guardo correctamente la información del cliente en la BD
  $details = [
    'title' => 'Mail from Laravel',
    'body' => 'This is for testing email using smtp'
  ];
  Mail::to($cliente->emailContacto)->send(new \App\Mail\RegisterClientMail($details));
  //Aquí debería enviar el email
}
catch(\Exception $e){
  return $e->getMessage();
} 

return response()->json([
            "success" => true,
            "message" => "Cliente creado exitosamente",
            "file" => $file
        ]);
```

El flujo nunca llega hasta el return final y tampoco marca algún tipo de error, solo me retorna la vista del email con status 200 pero no hace el envió del correo

```
{
  "data": "Undefined variable: details (View:C:\\XXX\\API\\resources\\views\\emails\\checkRegister.blade.php)",
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
   .
   .
   .
  }
```

En RegisterClientMail.php tengo:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Mail;

 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

 class RegisterClientMail extends Mailable
 {
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

 /**
  * Create a new message instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct($details)
  {
    //
    $this->details = $details;
  }

  /**
   * Build the message.
   *
   * @return $this
   */
  public function build()
  {
    return $this->subject('Se ha registrado como cliente')    
                ->view('emails.checkRegister');
    //return $this->view('view.name');
  }
}
```

En checkRegister.blade.php tengo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>ItsolutionStuff.com</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>{{ $details['title'] }}</h1>
  <p>{{ $details['body'] }}</p>
  <p>Thank you</p>
 </body>
```

Alguien me podría indicar que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: El mensaje de error te está diciendo que la variable `$details` no está definida en la vista `checkRegister`. Agrega el contenido de RegisterClientMail a la pregunta para ver qué lógica implementaste ahí, o sea cómo recibe esa variable, y cómo se la pasa a la vista

Comment: Gracias, actualizado con RegisterClientMail  y la vista

Comment: Si elimino los parametros de la vista me arroja este error: "Connection to tcp://mail.sxxx:465 Timed Out"

Comment: Si no me equivoco, te estaría faltando declarar la propiedad `public $details` en la clase RegisterClientMail. Revisa esto https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#via-public-properties